# PostGIS - create polygons from clusters of a fix number of points

Tags: postgis, clustering

I have a set of about 120,000 points, not regularly spread. 
[image]
I would like to cluster them in order to create groups of about 3,000 points, regardless the distance. The final goal is to create polygons (their size is not important, I just want them to contain 3,000 points) out of bbox from these groups. The result would be like a grid with different sizes of cells, each cell containing 3,000 points. Do you know how could I achieve this ? I saw st_clusterKmeans and st_clusterDBSCAN functions, but I don't know how to fix the number of points to aggregate (there's a minpoints with st_clusterDBSCAN, but no "maxpoints").

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/331342/93656) can do what you want; it's based on a `WITH RECURSIVE` approach, rerunning `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` on clusters with too many points. A smaller `params.fraction` value will increase execution time, but the amount of points per cluster will be closer to the `params.max_points` value. The goal was to get *below* `params.max_points`, not divide by exactly `params.max_points` points, so cluster sizes will vary below that threshold. Grid cells may very likely overlap, too.

Comment: your final polygons could be overlaped ?